# Matrix decomposition in a specific form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Can we prove that for any real valued $d\times d$ matrix $A$, $A$ can be decomposed to finite product of such matrices

$$A=\prod_{i=1}^n (I+R_i)$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\operatorname{rank}(R_i)=1$.

As far as I know, if there is $LDU$ or $LU$ decomposition to $A$, then we can easily figure out each $R_i$.

Comment: It suffices to do this for a Jordan block, and in fact we can also assume that the eigenvalue is $1$, and then I think a product of matrices $1+E_{j,j+1}$, with $E$ having a single $1$ in the indicated position, will work.

Comment: If $A$ is upper (or lower) triangular or diagonal, then we can use Frobenius matrices to achieve it. And the Jordan matrix belongs to this category. I'm wondering if the result holds for a permutation matrix or an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Use elementary row and column operations to decompose $A=PDQ$, where $P$ and $Q$ are naturally factored into the factors of the form $I+t\cdot E_{i,j}$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Now $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is a product of diagomal matrices $I+(1-d_i)\cdot E_{i,i}$, each of those either equals $I$ or is of the required form.

Comment: What if, say, $A_{11}=0$? In this case we are unable to apply such operations. I guess your operation is almost the same as the LU decomposition.